# Show row data in columns side by side in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `EmployeeObjective` like this:

```
EmployeeID  Objective   Weightage 
----------------------------------
1             A            20
1             B            20
1             C            20
1             D            20
1             E            20
```

I want to show the above table like below

```
EmployeeID  Objective1  Objective1Weightage Objective2 Objective2Weightage......to Objective10 Objective10Weightage
 1           A                 20            B              20     .............      Empty     Empty
```

Can this be done using `Pivot` or any other way?

Comment: A pivot won't work here, I'd advice you to do a `UNPIVOT FOR col IN (Objective,Weightage)` first and then do a `PIVOT`. Please try and let me know if you're not able to get it

Comment: how would i do `unpivot` ? i think `unpivot` can done on data in `pivot` form. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @user1891251 not necessarily, you could do the `UNPIVOT` as follows,
`SELECT * FROM <yourtable> UNPIVOT(val FOR col IN (Objective,Weightage)) unpiv` . Also make sure the data types of cols Objective,Weightage are the same.

For the above `UNPIVOT` result do a `PIVOT` which would get you the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #emp (EmployeeID  INT, Objective VARCHAR(10), Weightage INT)
INSERT INTO #emp VALUES
(1,'A',20),
(1,'B',20),
(1,'C',20),
(1,'D',20),
(1,'E',20)

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT EmployeeID,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Objective) AS Objective,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Weightage) AS Weightage,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rno 
FROM #emp )

SELECT * FROM (

SELECT EmployeeID, Val, Col+CAST(rno AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Col
FROM CTE
UNPIVOT(Val FOR Col IN (Objective,Weightage) ) unpiv ) a
PIVOT (
MAX(Val) FOR Col IN ([Objective1],[Weightage1],[Objective2],[Weightage2],[Objective3],[Weightage3],[Objective4],[Weightage4],[Objective5],[Weightage5])) piv
```

Comment: precise and efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
        EmployeeID,

        objective1 = max(obj1),
        weightage1 = MAX(weig1),
        objective2 = max(obj2),
        weightage2 = MAX(weig2),
        objective3 = max(obj3),
        weightage3 = MAX(weig3),
        objective4 = max(obj4),
        weightage4 = MAX(weig4),
        objective5 = max(obj5),
        weightage5 = MAX(weig5)
            from
    (
    select
        EmployeeID,
        Objective,
        Weightage,   
        'obj'+cast(row_number() over (partition by EmployeeID order by EmployeeID) as varchar(50)) as O,
        'weig'+cast(row_number() over (partition by EmployeeID order by EmployeeID) as varchar(50)) as W
    FROM table_name)temp
        pivot(max(Objective) for O in (obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5)) PivO
        pivot(max(Weightage) for W in (weig1, weig2, weig3, weig4, weig5)) PivW

    group by EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i manage to get the output with below query.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL 
    ,Objective NVARCHAR(250)
    , ObjectiveWeightage DECIMAL(6,4) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @T
(EmployeeID, Objective, ObjectiveWeightage)
   VALUES (1, 'A', 5 )
        , (1, 'B', 10   )
        , (1, 'C', 15   )
        , (1, 'D', 20   )
        , (1, 'E', 5    )
        , (1, 'F', 51   )
;WITH CTE_Rank AS
    (
    SELECT EmployeeID
        , Objective
        , ObjectiveWeightage 
        , sObjective = 'Objective' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY Objective) AS VARCHAR(10))
        , sObjectiveWeightage  = 'ObjectiveWeightage' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY Objective) AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM @T
    )

SELECT EmployeeID 
    ,MAX( Objective1) Objective1 
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage1)ObjectiveWeightage1
    ,MAX( Objective2         )Objective2 
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage2)ObjectiveWeightage2
    ,MAX( Objective3         )Objective3
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage3)ObjectiveWeightage3
    ,MAX( Objective4         )Objective4
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage4)ObjectiveWeightage4
    ,MAX( Objective5         )Objective5
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage5)ObjectiveWeightage5
    ,MAX( Objective6         )Objective6
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage6)ObjectiveWeightage6
    ,MAX( Objective7         )Objective7
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage7)ObjectiveWeightage7
    ,MAX( Objective8         )Objective8
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage8)ObjectiveWeightage8
    ,MAX( Objective9         )Objective9
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage9)ObjectiveWeightage9
    ,MAX( Objective10        )Objective10
    ,MAX( ObjectiveWeightage10)ObjectiveWeightage10
FROM CTE_Rank AS R
    PIVOT(MAX(Objective) FOR sObjective IN ([Objective1], [Objective2], [Objective3], [Objective4],[Objective5],[Objective6],[Objective7],[Objective8],[Objective9],[Objective10])) AS EmployeeObjective
    PIVOT(MAX(ObjectiveWeightage) FOR sObjectiveWeightage IN (ObjectiveWeightage1, ObjectiveWeightage2, ObjectiveWeightage3, ObjectiveWeightage4,ObjectiveWeightage5,ObjectiveWeightage6,ObjectiveWeightage7,ObjectiveWeightage8,ObjectiveWeightage9,ObjectiveWeightage10)) AS EmployeeObjectiveWeightage
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```